# How to configure field annotated with @Mock in Spring Boot Unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to test a `@RestController` by mocking out the `@Service` that is injected into it. I'm able to make the request to the mocked service but I can't seem to customize its mocking behavior. Is it not possible to combine `@Mock` and `doThrow(...)`? Or could something be wrong with my when clause?

My code:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class LessonControllerTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private LessonService service;

    @InjectMocks
    private LessonController controller;

    @Test
    public void some_good_test_name() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();

        Mockito.doThrow(new SignUpFailed("Test fail"))
            .when(service).addAttendeeToLesson(
                Mockito.any(Attendee.class), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()
            );

        final String requestJson = """ 
        {
            "email": "email@example.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "message": "Hello"
        }
        """;

        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/lessons/123/attendees")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .content(requestJson)
            )
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json("{}"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the 2nd parameter for the service call was a String that was being injected by @Value, so in the test that became null and anyString didn't match it.

Rather than using the ReflectionUtils to set the value of this @Value field I've rewritten my Controller to use constructor injection instead, moving the @Autowired and @Value annotations to a constructor.